# Is a line formed by two points greater than 45 degrees off of the horizontal

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to find out if a line defined by two points is greater than or equal to 90 degrees compared to the horizontal. Here is the code I used

```
bool moreThan90 = false;
double angle = Math.Atan((double)(EndingLocation.Y - Location.Y) / (double)(EndingLocation.X - Location.X));
if (angle >= Math.PI / 2.0 || angle <= -Math.PI / 2.0)
    moreThan90 = true;
```

Did I do this correctly or is there a better built in function in .Net that will find this?

EDIT -- Actually I messed up my question I ment to say 45 off of horizontal not 90. however the answers got me to a point where I can figure it out (really I just needed to be pointed at Atan2).

Comment: Do you mean 'Does the line defined by points x and y intersect a horizontal line at an angle greater than 90 degrees ?'  If you do, the answer is yes (draw a couple of examples to convince yourself of this) unless the line is vertical or horizontal.  This should lead you to refining your question.

Comment: I know the math is correct, I was wonder if there is a better built in function that is more efferent (I hate doing floating point division if I don't have to).

Comment: @Scott Chamerlain take a look at my answer, this is do-able without any division if you are using the horizontal for the X-Axis every time.

Comment: @Slaks - As per my original (wrong) question  Pheelicks is the most efficient answer.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - why specifically would you hate to do floating point division?

Comment: @Daniel, because I had it pounded in to me (and this may be cargo cult programming) that FP and division are both bad and you should avoid it when possible.(I originally learned programming in assembly on a Motorola HC11 where a division took magnitudes longer than any other op.)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - I thought that might be it. :) Intel chips have had integrated hardware FP support for over 20 years now, so it's probably time for you to do some simple benchmarks to see how many picoseconds you are worrying about. The CLR JIT makes full use of hardware FP instructions - indeed some of the methods in `Math` compile to single x86 instructions. e.g. http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/square-roots-are-slow/

Comment: Floating point still means rounding errors though, regardless of hardware support, so if it can be easily avoided, as it can here, then I don't see any point in introducing imprecision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A line that is more than 90 degrees from the horizontal will have its EndLocation.x at a smaller x value than Location.x.

So you don't need all the atan nonsense, this should be enough:

```
if (EndingLocation.X < Location.X)
    moreThan90 = true;
```

EDIT:

Seems the OP meant 45 degrees not 90, which means that the above simplification no longer holds. For this it might be better to use atan2 (as Slaks pointed out) But in the spirit of not using tan:

```
if (Math.Abs(EndingLocation.X - Location.X) > Math.Abs(EndingLocation.Y - Location.Y) && 
    EndingLocation.X < Location.X)
    moreThan45 = true;
```

Note that you only need the 2nd check if you only want lines which point to the right

Comment: Wrong.  This is more permissive than `Atan`

Comment: @SLaks, but it is correct. Assuming that your using the horizontal as the X-Axis, and @Scott Chamberlain said he would rather not do floating point division if he didn't have to.

Comment: Before downvoting, I suggest that you think - or draw a diagram. I am right

Comment: Seems reasonable to me given the question. (Perhaps the OP needs to reword it a bit)

Comment: I messed up my original question, I meant to say 45. you are correct for the 90 degree case. Edit your question so I can edit my vote

Comment: It seems correct to me with one little notice - depends on how you want to treat angles from 270 to 360 you may need to add ( || EndingLocation.Y < Location.Y).

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: you mean you asked about 90 degrees (a very special case) and pheelicks answered, and you downvoted his answer because it didn't fit the question you *meant*?

Comment: @Beta, yes, so I am asking him to edit his question so i can change my down vote to a up vote.

Comment: Thanks for the division-less answer, and I do need to check all four quadrants. EDIT - I would like to note that this would not work if you could have negative x and y values but in the system I am using i all numbers will be > 0. so this will work perfectly.

Comment: @Scott:  This will indeed work with negative numbers, and is exactly the answer I was going to give.  It is simply moving the first point to the origin, and checking the second point if ABS(X) > ABS(Y), which tells you which side of the line y = x (or y = -x) the point is on.

Comment: You are right, I was doing the abs before the subtraction in the math in my head.

Answer (score 3):

You should call [`Math.Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx), like this:

```
double angle = Math.Atan2(EndingLocation.Y - Location.Y, 
                          EndingLocation.X - Location.X);

if (Math.Abs(angle) >= Math.PI / 2.0)
    moreThan90 = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't imagine that there is a library method for finding the angle between the two vectors, you doing this correctly (the math is right) and a quick glance around msdn and google didn't provide me with anything.  I would use SLaks' version of calling the `Math.Atan` method.

An interesting thing to note since you are using the 'horizontal' as your plane to determine if the angle is greater than 90 degrees. If endingLocation.x < Location.X your angle will always be 'greater' than 90 degrees, if you are measuring from the positive X-Axis.

**Edit:** 
Original question was changed to 45 degree check.

The section below is a discussion of how to do this without doing floating point division per a comment that the OP made.

To find out if you have a 45 degree angle we know a few things without actually having to call `ATan` on the points.

first the slope of a 45 degree angle is 1. So if

`Math.Abs((EndLocation.y - location.y)/(EndLocation.X - Location.X)) > 1`

You have an angle that is > 45 degrees, however as permutations of a 45 degree angle occur 4 times in a circle. We need to check a few things.

If `EndLocation.X < Location.X` then the angle is greater than 45 degrees. This represents all angles that are left of the Y Axis (90 - 270). To determine if the angle is greater than 45 degrees we only need to know if the absolute value of the slope is greater than 1. This will always be true for the following.

`Math.Abs(EndLocation.Y - Location.Y) > Math.Abs(EndLocation.X - Location.X)`.

So with a if statement following something like

`If (EndLocation.X < Location.X) OrElse (Math.Abs(EndLocation.Y - Location.Y) > Math.Abs(EndLocation.X - Location.X) Then AngleGreaterThan45 = True.`

We can determine if the angle is greater than 45 degrees without the need to perform any floating point calculations.